# Why are the line breaks gone when I retrive data from my SQL database?

Tags: php, html

I've made a site where the user can type somthing in a textarea. The text is then saved to a databse I have at phpMyAdmin. However, when I retrive the data from the database, and 'echo' it on the screen, all the line breaks the user have included, is gone.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

I've tried with different things like including a button for 'new line' in the UI, but that's not very convenient. I wonder if there's any other way of displaying the line breaks?

Comment: You need to use [nl2br()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Comment: Html and plain text use different notation for line breaks. So what you see will depend on the output context

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to display the text *exactly* as it was entered on a web page, perhaps a `<pre></pre>` block may work best for you.

It would be best if you did more to sanitize any user-provided text you intend on returning to a browser, though, to avoid XSS and other exploits.

For example, what if a user sent you a script block, and you returned that to any one's browser?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use the nl2br() function:

```
$text = "Hello,
world!";
echo nl2br($text);
```

This will echo:

```
Hello,<br>
world!
```